# Is it legal to carry any kind of weapon in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, weapons

Concealed or otherwise is it legal for a private citizen to carry any kind of weapon for self defence purposes in the UK?

Comment: I think you'll need to focus this question down further.  In particular, what do you mean by "weapon"?  Obviously there are some objects that could be used as weapons and can legally be carried (rocks, umbrellas, soft cushions) and others that are not legal (bazookas, nuclear warheads).  Also, the part about reasoning is likely off topic for this site (though you could take it to Politics.SE); Parliament doesn't have to explain its reasoning when it creates laws.

Comment: @NateEldredge but a wise parliament does do so if they want the judiciary to apply those laws in light of their reasons.

Comment: The stated reasoning behind laws is a topic for Politics.SE. But the rest of the question is not, which is why I rejected the migration to Politics.SE. Law.SE community, please tell Ben what laws apply to weapon carrying in the UK. He can then go to Politics.SE and ask why these laws exist.

Comment: If one could legally carry a jar of marmalade for "self defence purposes," would that satisfy your question?  I realize that seems facetious, but it isn't; I'm asking for clarification of "any kind of weapon."  In other words, if there exists at least one weapon that may be legally carried in the UK, does that mean that the answer to your question is "yes"?  I'm asking because there are certainly weapons that may not be carried legally, so if you are asking whether such purpose allows one to carry a weapon (no matter what kind), the answer is "no."

Comment: Yes (ten more chars)

Comment: The question as phrased is ambiguous. It could mean "Is there any kind of weapon that someone can carry in self defense in Britain?" or it could mean is there a limitation the prevents you from carrying "any kind of weapon you choose to carry" even though you can can some kinds of weapons.

Answer (score 5):

JeffUK has quoted the relevant law.  However the question then becomes "what is an 'offensive weapon'", and "what is a lawful excuse?".

- Almost anything can be classified as an offensive weapon if you can use it as a weapon.  See https://www.askthe.police.uk/content/Q338.htm
- A lawful excuse is something like "I am going to play baseball, which is why I have a baseball bat".  It is emphatically *not* "I want it for self defence".  Specifically, https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/offensive-weapons-knives-bladed-and-pointed-articles cites

  > Patterson v Block [1984] 81 LSG 2458 – carrying a weapon for defence can still amount to intent to cause injury

So the answer to the OP's original question:

> Is it legal for a private citizen to carry any kind of weapon for self defence purposes in the UK?

is "No".

Answer (score 3):

Technically, no, you must have have reasonable excuse or lawful or authority to carry a weapon in public and 'Self Defense' is not normally a reasonable excuse.

However if you mean 'Can I do it without fear of prosecution'  then the answer is 'Yes' as long as you can provide a reasonable excuse when asked why you are carrying the weapon.

It's a very nuanced piece of law, the definition of a 'weapon' extends to practically any physical item.  It could be both illegal to carry a butter knife, and legal to carry a large machete depending on the circumstances.

> Possessing an offensive weapon in a public place is an offence contrary to s 1 of the Prevention of Crime Act 1953.
>
> To satisfy the charge, the prosecution must prove each of the following elements:
>
> - has with him (possession);
>
>   - in any public place;
>   - any offensive weapon.
>
> Having established all of the above, the charge would succeed, unless the accused proves that he had either:
>
> - lawful authority;
>
>   - or reasonable excuse.

[inbrief.co.uk](https://www.inbrief.co.uk/offences/offensive-weapon-possessing/)

Comment: Note that "lawful excuse" is something like "I am taking this baseball bat to play baseball", *not* "I want it for self-defense".

Comment: @MartinBonner updated answer to reflect the subtlety of the legal position.

Comment: Sorry.  Hadn't realized this was so old.

Comment: @MartinBonner no worries, SE answers are forever, no harm in improving them from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.gov.uk/buying-carrying-knives

The maximum penalty for an adult carrying a knife is 4 years in prison and an unlimited fine. You’ll get a prison sentence if you’re convicted of carrying a knife more than once.

Comment: Are "self defence purposes" (quoted from the question) acceptable as "good reason" (quoted from your source) for carrying a knife in public?  I would guess not.

Comment: The OP asked about "any kind of weapon," which presumably includes pepper spray and ball-point pens.

Comment: @phoog: If you anticipate a situation where you would want a weapon for self defense, then you should go out of your way to avoid that situation. Not go into that situation with a weapon.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but since we're at [Law.SE] it seems worthwhile to point out that for certain knives at least, the answer to the question depends on whether a court could find "self defence"  to be a "good reason," which you have not addressed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey perhaps the question is too broad, because it seems that the answer is that some articles are forbidden, while others are not.

Comment: @gnasher729. What happens if you own a farm in the middle of the countryside with no police around for miles. Then you are easy pickings for any mugger who wants to drive around the countryside to steal people's money and livestock or serial killer.