# Carrying a knife in public in the UK

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, weapons

Is carrying a certain knife in the UK, more specifically England, allowed? And what type of knives do these have to be? e.g. blade length.

Would carrying such knife be allowed if you do not have a valid reason to carry it such as needing it for work?

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/is-it-legal-to-carry-any-kind-of-weapon-in-the-uk, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31109/in-uk-law-what-items-can-you-carry-to-defend-your-person/31118#31118, https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29883/carrying-a-sgian-dubh-uk?rq=1

Comment: In particular one of them includes a link to https://www.gov.uk/buying-carrying-knives which might have the information you need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it legal to carry any kind of weapon in the UK?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/is-it-legal-to-carry-any-kind-of-weapon-in-the-uk)

Comment: This question is definitely duplicate between both the above mentioned by Nate Eldredge. Why it receives upvotes and an answer instead of being pointed to existing resources? Wo knows.

Comment: Ask yourself why you want to carry that knife. And if that knife was the cause of trouble, whether a judge would think you came up with some lame excuse.

Comment: If you need it for work, such as a Stanley knife for a carpenter, put it in your toolbox. If you feel unsafe in your area and want it for self defence, move house - you are far more likely to get [hurt by your own knife](https://www.met.police.uk/cp/crime-prevention/skc/stop-knife-crime/the-consequences-of-crime/).

Comment: @JamesGeddes if you're carrying the toolbox, surely you're carrying the contents? The toolbox acts as a reason.  But if you're up and down ladders all day, or in many other lines of work, a tool that's always to hand may be very useful.  Then you get into outdoor activities; things like a dive knife are essential safety equipment (or a rope-cutting knife readily at hand in whitewater kayaking in case a rescue goes wrong), but you're relying on subsection 4 if you're not getting paid

Comment: I am not a lawyer but as far as I know it is about context. For example, a baseball bat in the boot of your car along with baseballs and a baseball shirt is probably not a weapon, whereas the same baseball bat under your front seat is probably a weapon. Regardless of the legal minutia, the main point is *don't carry a knife*. Everyone, including you, will be better off for it.

Comment: @JamesGeddes surely you mean "don't carry a weapon" - of any kind with your bat comparison.  Agreeing with that, I've downsized to a keyring Victorinox from a 2"l one as a routine carry - it will do for opening boxes and the like,  and I've got toolkits at home/work/bike/car (actually a campervan).  Many of those have something more substantial tucked away with the spanners etc.  The kayaking one is personally relevant & tricky because the safety knife should be very accessible, ideally one hand-opening (which the law doesn't like) - but it's common to hang around in car parks ready to paddle

Comment: I do absolutely mean "Don't carry weapons". I agree with you, it can be handy to have a Leatherman or Swiss Army Knife *on occasion* but I would personally still not carry them on a daily basis, as they could be used against you. I own lots of tools that can do lots of good or lots of harm, so I keep them safe until I need them for that good.

Comment: @JamesGeddes NB a Leatherman isn't a folding pocket knife for these purposes;  generally locks.  In an old job I'd use my 2" Swiss Army knife multiple times per day, and kept it in my pocket (of my suit), but I drove straight  to work without meeting anyone.  It was when I went from "engineer" in that role back to "student" getting the bus to the city centre, that the proper penknife migrated to the desk drawer in favour of the tiny one that would almost escape notice, not be thought of as a weapon, but still be handy. If not in my pocket, it would be in my backpack - commuting bike tools

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130027/discussion-between-james-geddes-and-chris-h).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer:**

It depends. It is lawful if one has a lawful reason, such as it's needed for work, or it's a folding pocketknife (e.g. a Swiss Army Knife) with a blade less than 3 inches.

**Long answer:**

The primary legislation is [s.139 of the Criminal Justice Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/33/section/139?timeline=false) which makes it unlawful to have in a public place:

> (2) ... any article which has a blade or is sharply pointed except a folding pocketknife.

> (3) .... [this includes] a folding pocketknife if the cutting edge of its blade exceeds 3 inches.

Subsection (4) gives the "*good reason or lawful authority*" general defence for possessing such an article which is complemented and supplemented by:

> (5) Without prejudice to the generality of subsection (4) above, it shall be a defence for a person charged with an offence under this section to prove that he had the article with him—
>
> - (a)for use at work;
> - (b)for religious reasons; or
> - (c)as part of any national costume.

[This site](https://www.gov.uk/buying-carrying-knives) gives some more information and identifies certain knives that are banned, and [this site](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/offensive-weapons-knife-crime-practical-guidance), under "legislation", lists semi-related offences.

.

Comment: For (5)(c), does the national costume have to be of the person's own nationality? Or will any nationality do? Can you carry wear a Caribbean pirate nation costume and carry a cutlass, for example?

Comment: @reiab IMO the use of "any" in s.139(5)(c) would not limit possession to one's own nationality. For example, it is not uncommon for non-Scots to wear a kilt to weddings in England along with a [sgian-dubh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sgian-dubh). Also, I don't know (but doubt) if a pirate costume would be regarded as a national costume but if it is the onus would be on the possessor to prove it is on the balance of probabilities. (This is the lower standard used for most (all?) statutory defences.)

Comment: @reirab that's probably a grey area, where a judge may decide based on your reasons for wearing said costume. E.g. your pirate costume if worn for a fancy dress party would likely not allow a real cutlass but would allow a foam cutlass.

Comment: and if it's like the Dutch situation, a mayor or local police commander can temporarilly declare a complete ban on knives of any kind during for example a protest march or other "high risk event".

Comment: @reirab I very much doubt any court would consider a pirate costume national dress

Comment: @jwenting speaking anecdotally I don't think I've ever heard of that happening in the UK, though then again I haven't been on a protest march since before the Iraq war. Suspect anyone carrying non-pocket knives in such a circumstance though would have difficulty arguing it's legitimate.

Comment: The courts in the UK have generally interpreted justifiable reasons in an extremely narrow way. I would be extremely surprised if you could get away with pretending that the national dress of a country you have no association with is your justification for carrying a knife.

Comment: @Muzer ok, was going on what the mayors of major Dutch cities are doing which is just declaring the entire city a "no-knife zone" at random days and then having the police frisk anyone and confiscating everything they find (usually at the entrance to pedestrian zones and areas with bars and clubs). The legallity of those actions is dubious but so far none has been struck down by a court due to lack of people filing suit against them.

Comment: @Tristan Technically, a lot of the Caribbean pirates did form their own nation, mostly in the Bahamas. :) But, yeah, I'm guessing courts wouldn't look favorably on that.

Comment: @reirab whilst the republic of pirates was certainly a thing, it never enjoyed any international recognition. There's also no reason to believe it had a "national dress" in the sense intended here, let alone that it still has one, centuries after it ceased to exist

Comment: And I thought pirates could be arrested for just being pirates - cutlass or not...

Comment: ***NOTE:*** Per the court of Appeal, in the UK you can carry a folding blade less than three inches ***only*** if it does not lock open: "a ‘lock knife’ does not come into the category of ‘folding pocket knife’ because it is not immediately foldable at all times; (R v Deegan [1998] 2 Cr. App. R. 121 CA)" https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/186911/Knives_and_offensive_weapons_information_GDS_FAQ.pdf

Comment: @Ben Yes, that matters: many multi-tool manufacturers produce devices in which the knife blade is much shorter than all the other tools, in an attempt to comply with the "less than three inches long and folds into the body" test; but in some cases, the attempt fails, because the user has to press a switch to fold away the knife blade, making it a R v Deegan lock knife.

Comment: @reirab Or dress up as an medieval English knight and carry around a longsword... or maybe just something like a seax, depending on what the legal definition of "knife" is.

Comment: @Ben So, they literally have to _remove a safety feature_ in order to be able to carry it? I could sort of understand banning, say, switch blades, but why on Earth would you ban blade locks?

Comment: @reirab It gets worse. Parliament didn't do that. The courts wrote it in via interpretation. As written it just says "folding" without any special meaning, & ministers said in parliament it shouldn't have that effect. On the other hand parliament have had 23 years to correct it if they disagreed and haven't done so.